# Check if user liked the post

Tags: neo4j

I have the following query:

```
 MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post:Post)
 WITH user, post
 ORDER BY post.createdAt DESC
 OPTIONAL MATCH (post)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(comment:Comment)<-[:COMMENTED]-(:User)
 WITH user, post, liked, comment
 ORDER BY comment.timestamp DESC
 WITH user, post, liked, COLLECT(comment)[0..4] AS comments
 RETURN post,
        { username: user.username,
          firstName: user.firstName,
          lastName: user.lastName,
          profilePicture: user.profilePicture
        } AS createdBy,
        size((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)) AS likes,
        liked,
        comments
 SKIP {skip}
 LIMIT {limit}
```

The query gets list of posts and calculates other things like:
get post comments, get user who created the post, get total number of likes.

I need to also calculate if I liked the post or not, which will result into: userLiked (true|false).

I was thinking of something like:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (post)<-[userLiked:LIKES]-(:User {uuid: {userUUID}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a true/false, then EXISTS() is a better option.

You can also improve performance by moving your SKIP and LIMIT from the end of your query to after your ORDER BY for the post creation.

If you're using Neo4j 3.1.x or higher, you can use map projection to make it a little easier to return the fields you need on the createdBy map.

Here's your query with all these things included:

```
 MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post:Post)
 WITH user, post
 ORDER BY post.createdAt DESC
 OPTIONAL MATCH (post)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(comment:Comment)<-[:COMMENTED]-(:User)
 WITH user, post, comment
 ORDER BY comment.timestamp DESC
 WITH user, post, COLLECT(comment)[..4] AS comments
 SKIP {skip} LIMIT {limit}
 RETURN post, 
        user { .username, .firstName, .lastName, .profilePicture } AS createdBy,
        size((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)) AS likes,
        exists((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User{uuid: {userUUID}})) AS userLiked,
        comments
```

Comment: For this SKIP and LIMIT - doesn't work if I want paginate results.

Comment: Ah, makes sense if you want to order by comment timestamp first. I moved SKIP and LIMIT to just before the return, that should still prevent unnecessary operations on results that aren't in the page you plan on returning

Comment: Basically I want newest posts first which contains newest comments for every post. Looks like your edited post works fine. Thx!